# Abrir un archivo desde codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo html (codeslang.html) desde codeigniter.
Concretamente la llamada a este archivo html es desde js.

```js
function showModalPopUp(){
var popUpObj;
popUpObj= window.open('https://miweb.com/application/views/admin/codeslang.html',
"ModalPopUp",
"toolbar=no," +
"scrollbars=no," +
"location=no," +
"statusbar=no," +
"menubar=no," +
"resizable=0," +
"width=500," +
"height=500," +
"left = 250," +
"top=300"
);

popUpObj.focus();
LoadModalDiv();

}
```

Ya añadi la ruta en 'routes.php' pero no funciona

Me dice:
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Alguna sugerencia
Gracias

Comment: He intentado incluir el archivo html en el index.php de mi aplicacion pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, añadi un controlador que maneja el popup

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function pop(){ 
    $data = self::$data;
    $data = html_escape($this->security->xss_clean($data));
    $this->load->view('admin/codeslang',$data);
    return;
}
```

La llamada la realizo con la ruta
https://miweb/admin/pop